# RFC destinations

Tags: saprfc, sap-basis

Where can I get a description of RFCOPTIONS strings from a RFCDES table? What it means to each parameter? (H=?,N=?,g=?,l=?, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should see that in the transaction sm59:

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/48/89632084b84e6fe10000000a421937/frameset.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can find the mapping logic in function module RFCDISPLAY2RFCDES.

Here's a list of some of the main ones:

- H=hostname/IP address
- S=system number
- M=client number
- U=RFC user
- L=language
- X=load balancing (LB=ON)
- I=system ID
- N=logon group
- Z=auth related
- g=gateway server